# Is there some workaround to make requireJS point to webpack modules bundled with alias?

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs

Below are the pseudo configuration files for explanation purposes:

**webpack.config**

```
...
entry: {
    'animals': 'index' 
}
...
```

**index.js**

```
import * as Wolfs from './path/to/dogs';
import * as Tigers from './path/to/cats';
export {
  Wolfs,
  Tigers
}
```

**Configuration of RequireJS**

```
require.config( {
    ...
    'paths': {
        'dogs-requireJS-moduleID' : './path/to/dogs',
        'cats-requireJS-moduleID' : './path/to/cats',
        'animals-webpack-bundle'  : 'path/to/animals/bundle'           
     },
    'map': {
        '*': {
            'dogs-requireJS-moduleID': 'animals-webpack-bundle',
            'cats-requireJS-moduleID': 'animals-webpack-bundle'
         }
   });
```

**Dependent module**

```
import * as JohnDogs from 'dogs-requireJS-moduleID'; //This now points to animals-webpack-bundle 
JohnDogs.doStuff();
```

In order for the **Dependent module** to work, the code would have to be rewritten to `JohnDogs.Wolfs.doStuff()` because Dogs were exported with alias Wolfs. My question is if there is some workaround to make the code work without having to rewrite it.

Hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The above is only psudeo code for explanation purposes. In my real scenario, there are other projects with their own `webpack.config` that depend on this project that I am bundling but I can't access them. Also, these projects share the same RequireJS configuration to which I have access.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need requireJS to create aliases. You can do it in webpack like this (insert this snippet in your webpack.config.js file)

```js
const path = require("path");

/// ... webpack config
resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", "jsx", ".json"],
      alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"),
        models: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/models/"),
        pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/"),
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
      },
    },
```

Please note that if you're using Typescript, you will also need to write the aliases in your tsconfig.json:

```js
// ... compilerOptions
"paths": {
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
```

Then, you can import a file like this:

```js
import Slider from "components/form/slider"
```

Last but not least, an alias should point toward an entry point, like `components` or `assets`. Don't point them toward specific files like in your exemple, else you will end up with thousand of entries, it's just not scalable.

Comment: Unfortunately, creating an alias on webpack.config doesn't seem to solve my problem but thanks anyway. I updated my question for a better understanding.

Comment: Post your entire webpack config, so we can help. It's difficult to see the error. The alias resolution depend on the entry point (usually entry: "./src/index.tsx"). The webpack config should be at the root of your project, and all the js/ts files inside a src folder.